# JS 2 minute countdown then execute a function?

Tags: ajax, timer, javascript

I'm not that great at Javascript, for the record! I DO know how to use ajax. I just need a bit of help.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to display a 5 minute countdown, and once the countdown hits zero, to run a function. I need to pass a variable to the function that needs to run. I tried SetInterval but this isn't exactly my strong suit. Does anyone have any suggestions? I can post the code I've got, but I would equate it to a gorilla fumbling in the dark at a typewriter!

Comment: your question title says 2 minutes count and you questions description says 5 minutes count.... not that it really matter at all :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try it this way. Use `setTimeout()` to control the "timer" side of the requirement, or differently put, to control the count down on the screen.

When launching the `setTimeout()`, also launch the function call using `setInterval()`. `setInterval` can be used to launch functions after a certain amount of time, and will attempt to run it at those intervals. Once you have run your function though, just use a call to `clearInterval()` to stop the timer.

Below is some code adapted from a site, it's untested, but should get the idea across.

**Countdown Timer:** - From [here](http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Countdown-Timer.phtml), just modified a bit.

```
<form name="counter"><input type="text" size="8" 
name="d2"></form> 

<script> 
<!-- 
// 
 var interval="";
 var milisec=0;
 var seconds=300; 
 document.counter.d2.value='500';

function display(){ 
 if (milisec<=0){ 
    milisec=9;
    seconds-=1;
 } 
 if (seconds<=-1){ 
    milisec=0;
    seconds+=1; 
 } 
 else 
    milisec-=1;
    document.counter.d2.value=seconds+"."+milisec;
    setTimeout("display()",100);
    var interval = setInterval("goFunction(\" + seconds + \")", seconds);
} 
display();

goFunction(param)
{
   clearInterval(interval);
   // ... Do what needs doing
}
--> 
</script>
```